# nancy razorview intellisense

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I am using Nancy, self-hosting, with Razorview.  I am using VS 2010.

I cannot get intellisense working with razor view syntax in cshtml files.  I've been struggling with this for hours!  I'd really like intellisense with razor view syntax as I'm new to the razorview engine.

Comment: VS 2013-2015 are free. And Razor intellisense works with them

Comment: That's the route I eventually went.  I just wanted 2010 to work.  Probably should be using 2015 anyway. Thanks @MikeSW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up and just used VS 2015.  It worked immediately with the steps listed on NancyFX site.

Anyone struggling with this issue, save yourself some time and just use 2015. Razor intellisense doesn't appear to work with Nancy in Visual Studio 2010.